# Apache NIFI Processors Not Maintaining the State

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Querydatabasetable and generatetablefetch processors to fetch from Oracle, I gave maximum-value column for the incremental fetch. I'm not seeing this max-val column in view state.

we've two-node cluster, it did pull the data but didn't store the updated max-value. It stored the state before restarting the nifi VM though. problem exists after the restart.

I've changed the core-site.xml file on nifi and restarted the nifi vm, but then the processors are not showing the state of processor when I do "view state" on the processor.

I've added Zookeeper nodes onto state-management.xml, and it is also still not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain which processor you are using and what you are expecting to see in view state?

Comment: Hello Bryan, I'm using Querydatabasetable and generatetablefetch processors to fetch from Oracle, I gave maximum-value column for the incremental fetch. I'm not seeing this max-val column in view state.

Comment: Ok and do you have a cluster or standalone NiFi? and have you run the processor and it pulled data, but didn't store the updated max value?

Comment: we've standalone nifi Bryan, correct, it did pull the data but didn't store the updated max-value. It stored the state before restarting the nifi VM though. problem exists after the restart.

Comment: Hmm in standalone it uses the local-provider in state-management.xml which is a write ahead log on local disk stored at nifi_home/state/ by default

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please click edit and add the information you've provided as comments into the body of your question. People shouldn't have to read the comments to understand your question.

Comment: added comments onto question. Thanks Mozahler.